# Accessing to iPhone camera data only with API

Tags: ios, camera

I would like to access in real time to the data of the camera to get the hue of several points in order to guide the user (inform them when is the best moment to take the picture).

The application will be probably available on the appstore and then I want to just use allowed API. I've seen a lot of similar topics, some of them telling this is possible but none of them showing a solution.

Do you have any idea for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the undocumented `UIGetScreenImage()` function; an Apple representative recently stated their approval of the use thereof in the [iPhone developer forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/149553).

Comment: Thanks you for your fast answer! Do you have an example of this function? I do not have access to your link.

Comment: It takes no parameters and returns a pointer to a CGImageRef, which you are responsible for releasing. You should be able to log into the developer forums using your iPhone developer account credentials.